# Using Count rate can we calculate the activity?

Tags: radiation, radioactivity

In the inverse square law experiment:
We have a $^{137}$Cs emitted gamma photons at 662 keV. Using a detector and a ruler found the relationship between the distance and intensity ( Counts/Sec). Can we calculate the activity of the source ? Is the formula $$\frac {x}{t}= \frac{A(\mathrm{Gamma Constant})}{d^2}$$ applicable here?

Comment: I don't recognize what "(Gamma Consent)" is. Is "(x/t)" supposed to be the count rate?

Comment: Exposure from a point source – The Specific Gamma-ray constantd (X/t) = AΓ/d^2

Answer (score 0):

In order to calculate the absolute activity, you would need to know the solid angle of the detector and the efficiency of the detector at the energy of the photon. The inverse square law will account for changes in solid angle, but doesn't tell you the actual solid angle. The solid angle depends on the detector size and the distance.

The efficiency will depend on the specific type of detector (gas-filled, solid state, scintillation, etc), the bias voltage. Once you've chosen a detector and fixed the bias voltage, the efficiency at 662 keV could be a constant. But you still need to know the absolute efficiency to find the absolute activity.

Comment: If the detecor was GM. How I will find the absolute efficiency ?

Comment: The answer to *"How I will find the absolute efficiency ?"* is *always* "With considerable difficulty" if you want any precision in that figure but a starting place is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_efficiency